# Use of UIView to abstract away common UI (much like a "partial" in web) drawRect vs init vs layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to make my View Controllers leaner by abstracting common UI away into UIView subclasses and just instantiating them in my VCs, much like I would create HTML templates in web dev.

Here is my VC:

```
- (void)addEmptyView {
    self.emptyHomeView = [[PLOTEmptyHomeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 113) andUser:self.userModel.user];
    [self.view addSubview:self.emptyHomeView];
}
```

And the UIView I subclass and instantiate:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUser:(NSDictionary *)user {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        self.user = user;
        [self drawUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawUI {
    self.arrowUp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-up"]];
    CGRect arrowUpFrame = self.arrowUp.frame;
    arrowUpFrame.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width - 60;
    arrowUpFrame.size.width = 33.75;
    arrowUpFrame.size.height = 33;
    self.arrowUp.frame = arrowUpFrame;
    [self addSubview:self.arrowUp];

    self.welcome = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 167.5, self.bounds.size.width, 22.5)];
    NSArray *nameParts = [self.user[@"name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    self.welcome.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey %@", nameParts[0]];
    self.welcome.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:24];
    self.welcome.textColor = [UIColor plotPlaceholderGrey];
    self.welcome.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:self.welcome];
}
```

Now this code all works fine, but for my own understanding, am I abusing the `init` method? I'm also aware of `layoutSubviews` & `drawRect` in `UIView` but i'm not sure if I should be using them in the above scenario?

Any pointers are appreciated...

Comment: If you are in a UIViewController subclass all of this code should go in 'viewDidLoad'

Comment: @atreat "And the UIView I subclass and instantiate:" - I'm not

Comment: Yep, just read that. In a UIView this is a fine pattern. You could make the drawUI public in the header file and then after you init the view call `[self.emptyHomeView drawUI]` but there is not much difference there. I would recommend implementing `initWithCoder` and adding a call to drawUI there. That is just future proofing if you ever refactor this view using interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not abusing of init method, but you have to declare all your ui objects and all their properties without define the frame and in the layoutsubviews, you define the frame of all your object. It's my way to declare an custom view.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUser:(NSDictionary *)user {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
      self.user = user;
      self.arrowUp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-up"]];
     [self addSubview:self.arrowUp];
     self.welcome = [[UILabel alloc] init];


   NSArray *nameParts = [self.user[@"name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    self.welcome.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey %@", nameParts[0]];
  self.welcome.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:24];
  self.welcome.textColor = [UIColor plotPlaceholderGrey];
  self.welcome.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  [self addSubview:self.welcome];

   }
   return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
   CGRect arrowUpFrame = self.arrowUp.frame;
   arrowUpFrame.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width - 60;
   arrowUpFrame.size.width = 33.75;
   arrowUpFrame.size.height = 33;
   self.arrowUp.frame = arrowUpFrame;

  self.welcome.frame =CGRectMake(0, 167.5, self.bounds.size.width, 22.5)];
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Optimally, you can instantiate and add subviews in your method as shown, but do actual layout involving frames in `layoutSubviews`. The code you have will work as is, but if your initialize would be from a nib or something that doesn't provide the core frame (or autolayout was involved) you may not truly know the proper bounds/frame at init time. Often layout code is dependent on other factors that may change so `layoutSubviews` is a more proper location.